# Unable to ssh between the servers via command line

Tags: linux, rhel

I have three machines, let's say **10.49.1.101**, **10.49.1.102**, **10.49.1.103**. These IP's are also present each other in `/etc/hosts` file. If I simply do `ssh` between these machines it works completely fine. But If I try to remove folder using `ssh` something like this from **10.49.1.101**

```
for rs in `cat "ip-s"`; do echo $rs; ssh $rs "rm -rf path/to/dir"; done
// ip-s contains all the 3 server ips
```

will throw a below error and it won't succeed. But it works from **10.49.4.102**, **10.49.4.103**

```
: Name or service not knownname 10.49.1.102
: Name or service not knownname 10.49.1.103
```

FYI, These are the redhat versions

- 10.49.1.101 - Redhat 7.7
- 10.49.1.102 - Redhat 6.6
- 10.49.1.103 - Redhat 6.6

Is it a redhat-7.7 version problem. If yes, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be such a problem, is there a spelling error, when running directly from the command line there are similar errors reported? You used `IP` to `SSH`, but the prompt seems to be related to  `DNS`

Comment: If I try `SSH hostname`, It works again. I verified the spelling in `/etc/hosts`. No mistakes found

Comment: @山河以无恙  did I answered your question?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. It's a strange thing. In fact, it won't happen